# Widows azure cache not working with Windows Azure Storage 3.1

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-caching

I have upgraded my Azure Storage DLL from version 2.1 to 3.1. I have a cache storage on Azure and I am not able to make it work with the new version of Storage 3.1.0.1. I'm getting a `MethodAccessException` when trying to create an instance of `DataCacheFactoryConfiguration`. My code:

```
var conf = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration("myconfig"); //exception here
var cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(conf);
_dataCache = cacheFactory.GetCache("mycache");
```

The `web.config` section is well configured. I don't know if I am missing something on how to access the cache with the new version of azure storage. I'm not able to find a solution. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
The problem is not related with the DLL version, I've tried it in another machine and it worked. I think that the machine that's causing the problem has too many references to too many versions of Azure SDK. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of SDK and Caching library are you using?

Comment: what OS are you using on Azure? did you try with the latest windows 2014 r2?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade SDK to 2.3. It will install all the dependencies

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn655054.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip (+1), but it didn't work neither. It is something related with the machine I'm using, I've tried in another one and it works fine. As soon as I find the bug, I'll post an answer.